# How can I fix Inconsistent line thickness in ionic lists and inputs?

Tags: angular, ionic2

[image]

If you look closely, you will notice that there is inconsistent thickness with the line underneath  each of the list items. Yet on the bottom one, the thickness is okay. Toward the edge they are thinner and this makes for a really terrible UI. It is even worse in the inputs.

I have removed every line of my own css and have noticed no difference.

Has anyone had the same problem? I have banged my head on the wall a few times because of this, Please help?

Comment: can you add the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT! It was a problem with the SCSS in a plugin i had installed.